# NTEventLogHandler from a Python executable

Tags: python, logging, pywin32, pyinstaller

```
import logging, logging.handlers

def main():
    ntl = logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler("Python Logging Test")
    logger = logging.getLogger("")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(ntl)
    logger.error("This is a '%s' message", "Error")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Python (2.7.x) script above writes "This is a 'Error' message" to the Windows Event Viewer. When I run it as a script, I get the expected output. If I convert the script to an executable via PyInstaller, I get an entry in the event log but it says something completely different.

> The description for Event ID ( 1 ) in Source ( Python Logging Test ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: This is a 'Error' message.

This is the command I use to convert the script into an executable: `pyinstaller.py --onefile --noconsole my_script.py` though the command line parameters do not appear to have any impact on this behaviour and it will suffice to just call `pyinstaller.py my_script.py`.

I would appreciate any help in understanding what is going on and how I go about fixing this.

**Final solution**

I didn't want to go down the resource hacker route, as that is going to be a difficult step to automate. Instead, the approach I took was to grab the `win32service.pyd` file from c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32 and place it next to my executable. The script was then modified pass the full path to the copy of the `win32service.pyd` file and this works in both script and exe form. The final script is included below:

```
import logging, logging.handlers
import os
import sys

def main():
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    dllname = os.path.join(base_dir, "win32service.pyd")

    ntl = logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler("Python Logging Test", dllname=dllname)
    logger = logging.getLogger("")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(ntl)
    logger.error("This is a '%s' message", "Error")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, the Windows Event Log doesn't store error messages in plain text, but rather message ID references and insertion strings.

Instead of storing a message like `Service foo crashed unexpectedly`, it stores a message ID which points to a resource string stored in a DLL. In this case, the resource would be something like `Service %s crashed unexpectedly` and `foo` would be stored as insertion string. The program which writes the message registers the resource DLL.

The reason for this is localization. DLLs can store lots of different resources (dialog layout, strings, icons…), and one DLL can contain the same resource in many different languages. The operating system automatically chooses the right resources depending on the system locale. Resource DLLs are used by virtually all Microsoft utilities and core utilities.

<sub>Side note: Nowadays, the preferred (and cross-platform) way for localization is `gettext`.</sub>

This is used for the message log as well – ideally, you could open a log from an German Windows installation on an English one with all messages in English.

I suspect that the pywin32 implementation skips that mechanism by only having one single message ID (1) which is just something like `"%s"`. It is stored in `win32service.pyd` and registered by pywin32. This works fine as long as this file exists on the file system, but breaks as soon as it's hidden inside a PyInstaller executable. I guess you have to embed the message ID into your executable directly.

**Edit:** suspicion confirmed, the message table is indeed stored inside `win32service.pyd`

[Resource Hacker showing the message table http://media.leoluk.de/evlog_rh.png](http://media.leoluk.de/evlog_rh.png)

Try to copy the message table resource from `win32service.pyd` to your PyInstaller executable (for example using [Resource Hacker](http://media.leoluk.de/evlog_rh.png)).

Looking at the logging handler implementation, this might work:

```
def __init__(self, appname, dllname=None, logtype="Application"):
    logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    try:
        import win32evtlogutil, win32evtlog
        self.appname = appname
        self._welu = win32evtlogutil
        if not dllname:
            dllname = os.path.split(self._welu.__file__)
            dllname = os.path.split(dllname[0])
            dllname = os.path.join(dllname[0], r'win32service.pyd')
```

You'd have to set `dllname` to `os.path.dirname(__file__)`. Use something like this if you want it to continue working for the unfrozen script:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    dllname = None
elif __file__:
    dllname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

ntl = logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler("Python Logging Test", dllname=dllname)
```

Comment: This sounds somewhat plausible. How do I go about fixing this? Register win32service.pyd manually? How do I embed the message ID in my executable? Are there any articles/tutorials that demonstrate this as most articles on logging just point to the standard Python class docs and that's not much help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @CadentOrange I am bumping into this issue as well. But I cannot figure out how to fix it using this solution.  Could you elaborate a bit more?