# NTEventLogHandler and "The description cannot be found"

Tags: python, windows, logging, event-log

When trying to log something using NTEventLogHandler, I get the following message in "View Events":

"The description for Event ID ( 1 ) in Source ( Python Logging Test ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. ..."

Logger initialization is as follows:

```
def _create_windows_service_log(self):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        dllname = None
    elif __file__:
        dllname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    ntl = logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler(self._app_name, dllname, self._app_name)

    self._logger = logging.getLogger(self._app_name)
    self._logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self._logger.addHandler(ntl)
```

And its use is like that:

```
self._logger.info(a_msg)
```

I checked the data in the registry. The key "EventMessageFile" indicates the correct path to the file "win32service.pyd".

I tried to use that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784033/nteventloghandler-from-a-python-executable), but it didn’t work.

Comment: Saw your comment. See the bit I quoted in my answer - `win32service.pyd` only contains some basic placeholder message definitions, not necessarily your message ID.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.NTEventLogHandler) about the `dllname` parameter:

> The dllname should give the fully qualified pathname of a .dll or .exe which contains message definitions to hold in the log (if not specified, 'win32service.pyd' is used - this is installed with the Win32 extensions and contains some basic placeholder message definitions ...)

I think that if the message IDs aren't found in the named DLL, you will get this problem. You seem to be passing `dllname` as either `None` or the name of a directory, which can't be a DLL!

Comment: I checked, dllname contains a path to win32service.pyd